# npm-check-updates (npm ncu): avoid breaking updates

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

The command `npm-check-update` displays mayor updates in red. This can be already seen in the [first image of the documentaton](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).
But is there a way to exclude these breaking changes from the automatic update? I do not find a parameter for that.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually in the readme file:
[image]

So, just do a `ncu -t minor -u` to leave major version updates out (those that are most likely to break things).

Answer (score 1):

For my part I do :

```
ncu -u -x axios,eslint,eslint-plugin-prettier,eslint-plugin-vue,sass-loader,@tinymce/tinymce-vue,vue-browser-detect-plugin
```

All dependencies after "-x" are major upgrade for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).